# line graph with 2 categorical variables and 1 continuous in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, categorical-data, linegraph

I'm quite new to R and statistics in general. I am trying to plot in a line graph 2 categorical variables (part of speech "pos", condition "trcond")  and a numerical one (score "totacc") in ggplot2.

```
> df1<-df[, c("trcond", "subtitle", "pos", "totacc")]
> head(df1)
   trcond     subtitle pos totacc
7       L New Scene_16 lex  0.250
29      N New Scene_16 lex  0.500
8       L New Scene_25 lex  0.875
30      N New Scene_25 lex  0.666
9       L New Scene_29 lex  1.000
31      N New Scene_29 lex  0.833
```

I have used this ggplot2 command:

```
>ggplot(data=summdfo, aes(x=pos, y=totacc, group=trcond, colour=trcond))
+ geom_line() + geom_point()
```

But it is not working, the graph has coloured (blue and red) dots all over the place and more than just two lines linking them. I would like to post the graph I get as I lack words to explain but this is my first post and I don't seem to be able to upload pictures.

I would like to get a standard simple 2-line graph such as the blue and red ones in this page (where y=total bill, by x=time (lunch,dinner) grouped by gender): http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_%28ggplot2%29/

Is this possible with my data set at all? If so, what am I doing wrong with the code?

Comment: How is `summdfo`, the data frame passed to `ggplot`, defined?

Comment: If you are allowed to share the dataset, enter `dput(summdfo)` and place the output in your example.  This will enable others to hopefully reproduce your error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here I tried to create a data frame based on limited sample from your data.

```
df1 <- data.frame(trcond=rep(c('L', 'N'), 3), 
                  subtitle=rep('New Scene_29', 6),  # Not in use, just a dummy
                  pos=c('lex', 'lex', 'lex', 'noLex', 'noLex', 'noLex'), 
                  totacc=c(0.250, 0.5, 0.875, 0.666, 1.000, 0.833))
```

Because trcond by pos is not balanced in this data frame, the plot is going to be jumbled up like this:

```
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=pos, y=totacc, group=trcond, color=trcond))+ 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]
However, if you apply a summary function which will compute means for each condition, a correct plot will appear:

```
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=pos, y=totacc, group=trcond, color=trcond))+ 
  geom_line(stat='summary', fun.y='mean') + 
  geom_point(stat='summary', fun.y='mean')
```

[image]
Again, this is trying to figure out what's in your data. The best is that you provide here a sample of your data using dput(head(df1, 50)) to give you a better answer.

Comment: the command dput(head(df1, 50)) yields a lot of output. For future reference, am I allowed to post it in full here? Thanks for the explanation arman, now it makes sense why my line graph was jumbled up. I have just tried adding fun.y='mean' and it produces the output I was expecting!

Comment: Glad that it works :). Regarding dput(head(df1, 50)), you can either try a number smaller than 50, such as 10 or 20. However, it may not be meaningful of you have many conditions and they are not covered. Alternatively, if you are allowed to share the whole dataset, saving the variable as a CSV file (write.csv(df1, file='df1.csv') and share it on Dropbox. Then follow instructions [here](http://is.gd/Gc08hv) to load the CSV file over the secure URL.