# Generate line graph with categorical x using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I want to plot this made up population data.

```
dat <- data.frame(year_start_aby = c(-20, -10, 0, 10, -20, -10, 0, 10, -20, -10, 0, 10),
              year_end_aby = c(-10, 0, 10, 20, -10, 0, 10, 20, -10, 0, 10, 20),
              population = c(16000000, 19900000, 15300000, 16900000, 40000000, 55000000, 43100000, 50000000, 120000000, 125000000, 0, 0),
              planet = c("Tatooine", "Tatooine", "Tatooine", "Tatooine", "Naboo", "Naboo", "Naboo", "Naboo", "Alderaan", "Alderaan", "Alderaan", "Alderaan"))
```

I can easily plot population on a continuous x-axis by year_start_aby like this:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(year_start_aby, population, color = planet)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

But if I want the x-axis to be plotted as year range factors (-20 ABY -- 0 ABY, etc.) rather than continuous year values, how can I do this?

Help me, Obi-Wan Kenobi -- you're my only hope.

Comment: Try this `+scale_x_continuous(breaks=unique(dat$year_start_aby), labels=paste(unique(dat$year_start_aby),"ABY"))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [line graph with 2 categorical variables and 1 continuous in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082083/line-graph-with-2-categorical-variables-and-1-continuous-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a group aesthetic.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = factor(year_start_aby), y = population, group = planet, color = planet)) +
geom_line()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question. The lines are already grouped correctly.